# Setup Tomato router as wireless repeater

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-bridge, tomato, repeater

I've setup DD-WRT routers before as wireless repeaters ([link](https://superuser.com/q/1329970/153286)), but now I need to do the same but on a Tomato router, and apparently there's some difference in the terminology and the actual setup. What is equivalent to the DD-WRT "Client Bridge" mode in Tomato? Is it "Wireless Client" or "Wireless Ethernet Bridge" or something else?

I followed [this guide](https://learntomato.com/choose-wireless-bridge-mode-tomato-network/) and it suggests to use "Access Point + WDS" mode. So now I'm following [this instruction](https://learntomato.com/setup-wireless-repeater-wds-bridge-tomato/) to set it up, but it requires both primary and secondary routers to have Tomato FW, and run WDS on both routers. I only have Tomato on my repeater router. My primary router is running stock FW so it doesn't have the flexibility.

For my repeater router, ideally I want to run 1 radio band as the wireless bridge that connects to the primary router, and the 2nd radio band as an AP that connects to wireless clients. How do I config this?

---

Update:

I tried Wireless Ethernet Bridge mode on one radio and AP on another radio and it actually worked. I can connect to the repeater router and get Internet. However, the router (Linksys E4200) is very unstable in that mode. The router will reboot every 10 mins or so and each reboot took extra long time, I don't know what it's struggling with. The router had been extremely stable before when used as a regular AP router. Could it be some setting I didn't config correctly?

Comment: https://www.spideylab.com/tomato-router-wireless-repeater-ethernet-bridge-mode/ I think this may be what you are looking for. Replace the virtual (ath0.1) with your actual interface names if you want to use physical radios

Comment: Yes wireless ethernet bridge works but the router becomes very unstable...

Comment: Yep, that does happen on some routers. Try a different build.